# Функция .wrap ломается при подгрузке постов

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Всем привет. На сайте используется js-функция .wrap(), оборачивающая миниатюры записей на главной странице в див для придания пущей красоты картинкам.

```
$('.full-featured-posts-image img, .post-slider-image img').wrap("<div class='image-hover'></div>");
```

Там же используется подгрузка постов по нажатию на кнопку. Незадача в том, что подгруженные таким образом посты, теряют обертку дивом и стили соответственно. Кто-нибудь знает почему?

Comment: Потому что ваш скрипт не выполняется по ajax.

Comment: А вообще-то, это извращение. Оборачивать картинки в div надо в php, на этапе формирования выдачи поста.

Comment: Видел такое решение в одной теме. Сделал также, чтобы меньше ручками работать. Но да, удалил все на фиг, прописал в коде шаблонов)